# Fancybox error - reloads on click or focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, frontend

I have a fancybox with a form inside that is reloading every time I click or select a field. I've never seen this behavior before, and haven't found a way to fix it. Here's some code:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad : function(){console.log("FancyBox::beforeLoad()");},
    onCancel : function(){console.log("FancyBox::onCancel()");},
    beforeClose : function(){console.log("FancyBox::beforeClose()");},
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    keys  : {
        close  : null
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

> ```
> <div id="popup" class="fancybox" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; display: none;">
>   <h2>Submit</h2>
>   <div class="centered">
>     <form id="fancyform" role="form">
>       <div class="form-group">
>         <label for="post-title">Title:</label>
>         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post-title" placeholder="Title">
>       </div>
>       <div class="form-group">
>         <label for="post-url">URL:</label>
>         <input type="url" class="form-control" id="post-url" placeholder="Post URL">
>       </div>
>       <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
>     </form>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

This seems identical to this question: [Fancybox Error automatic reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751950/fancybox-error-automatic-reload), but the poster seems to have answered it himself, and the answer doesn't actually present a working solution.

Comment: Could you show what html are you using?

Comment: Sure! Added some html to the question.

Comment: here is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507562/1055987

Comment: bear in mind that every element with `class="fancybox"` will trigger fancybox ... so does your form inside the hidden `div` (which has the *class* `fancybox`) your easiest fix is to remove the `class="fancybox"` from the hidden `div` with `id="popup"`

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense now.